# Не устанавливается докер

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, elementary-os

Пытаюсь установить докер в убунту 18.04 (если точнее у меня ElementaryOS 5.0) по [офф инструкции](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). Дошел до 4 шага без проблем, но дальше никак:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет docker-ce недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «docker-ce» не найден кандидат на установку
E: Невозможно найти пакет docker-ce-cli
E: Невозможно найти пакет containerd.io
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «containerd.io»
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью регулярного выражения «containerd.io»
```

Стоит заметить, что при выполнении `yum update` я получил такие ошибки:

```
...

Ошб:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu juno Release                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.192.99.29 443]

...

Чтение списков пакетов… Готово                                                                                                                                
E: Репозиторий «https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu juno Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
```

Comment: Из документации ясно, что Docker имеет репозитории для xenial, bionic и cosmic, но не для juno

Comment: @andreymal а как же мне его установить туда? :(

Comment: Смотреть какому релизу убунты соответствует версия Минта. И прописывать её. А потом молиться, чтобы всё поехало. Просто Минт не особо юзают на серверах. Ну как "не особо" - вообще не юзают.

Comment: @donRumata во первых причем тут вообще Mint, если я сказал что у меня ElementaryOS? Во вторых у меня не сервер, а обычный ПК. Докер нужен для разработки. В третьих EOS 5 = Ubuntu 18.04 как я уже писал в самом начале темы.

Comment: "у меня ElementaryOS" - не вижу принципиальной разницы. Если бы у тебя была "настоящая убунта", то ошибки про "juno" просто не возникло бы. "Во вторых у меня не сервер, а обычный ПК" - ну попроси разрабов Докера добавить репы для неМинта или попроси разрабов ElementaryOS добавить докер в штатные репы. Тем не менее - моё первое предложение было бы неплохо прочитать ещё раз и попытаться сделать как там написано. Может поможет.

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал найти этот докер в штатных репозиториях. Авось он там есть, просто по-другому называется `apt search docker`.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать этот код вместо описанного на оффсайте.

> sudo add-apt-repository  "deb [arch=amd64]
>   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"

Мне на Linux Mint помогло. Возможно для ElementaryOS что-то будет отличатся. Но двигаться нужно точно в этом направлении.

Comment: спасибо, помогло